# Image/div reveal with css translate

Tags: html, css, transform, css-animations, translate-animation

I am a newbie/beginner to CSS animations and I have searched on StackOverflow but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I am looking to achieve the effect appearing on the second section of [this website](http://madebyritual.com)

The smooth easing "sweeping" reveal effect on the images. I can't manage to do it. Is there a way to do this with translate/ transform?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far? That might help people answer.

Comment: You could also show a small sample animation (GIF) of the desired effect ([how to embed images](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)).

Comment: Thanks,
Here's what I've managed to do so far : https://codepen.io/fvjun31/pen/NYovXz

I have the first sliding effect but I don't know how to make a second animation to show the image, overlaying the sliding div.

I don't want to use a GIF, I want to be able to do this in pure CSS.